# how to download pdf report using ga4 api?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-analytics-4

I use the GA4 API to display reports on the site, how can I download these reports in PDF?

Is there a way to do this without using third-party libraries to create PDF files? If not, what is the best way to use to download analytics reports?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.